# Installing Angular2 over package.json: UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, peer

Assumed I've an empty project with following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "EmptyNG2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Empty Description",
  "repository": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and now I want to install Angular2 with all its dependencies (what ever it needs) and use:

```
npm i -SDOEdd

i        for install
-S       save the installed packages into package.json
D        save Dependencies
O        save Optional Dependencies
E        use exactly the given version Angular -> 2.0.0-beta.17
dd       show me what you do (short version for --verbose)
```

**NPM recognizes the peer dependencies but still does not install them:**

```
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.12 but none was installed.
```

**Is there an additional key for that?**

EDIT: I know, it is not an angular-issue: angular2 ist just an interesting/modern example to show the problem in action.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Angular 2 issue.

Simply put, NPM does not install **peerDependencies** of other packages.

Angular has some peer dependencies which you need to install before installing angular.

[Here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11213) you can find some tricks in the last comment, there might be some npm packages out there that will do it for you, run a quick search and find out.

Anyway, this is the intended behaviour, nothing is wrong.

If you're interested in some history about why **peerDepdendencies** are not automatically installed read [Here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565)

Comment: hmm npm is ageing and getting really old :/ there must be an intelligent solution,.. That is not really an acceptable solution: `npm info . peerDependencies | sed -n 's/^{\{0,1\}[[:space:]]*'\''\{0,1\}\([^:'\'']*\)'\''\{0,1\}:[[:space:]]'\''\([^'\'']*\).*$/\1@\2/p' | xargs npm i`

Comment: You're right, but there are reasons removing peerDeps... I agree it's a hassle but I'm sure there are npm packages out there that help you with that